# i had two html file with and js file. both of them are connected usin broadcasting API. but they are showin different winner name in the slot machine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i had two different html file with and a js file. both of them are connected using broadcasting API. but they are showing different winner name in the slot machine. i want them to show same winners name. i tried storing the var names in different js but it won't work
this is the script for viewer.html

```
<script>
      
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var isDrawing = false;
    
          function startSlotMachine() {
            if (!isDrawing) {
              stopConfetti();
              runSlotMachine();
            }
          }
          var channel = new BroadcastChannel('slotMachineChannel');
          channel.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            if (event.data === 'startSlotMachine') {
              startSlotMachine();
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
```

this is the js file.

```
var names = ["Juan Dela Cruz", "Heneral Luna", "Jose Rizal"];
var isDrawing = false;
var confettiInterval;

function generateRandomLetter() {
  return String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
}

function runSlotMachine() {
  if (isDrawing) return;
  isDrawing = true;

  var slotContainer = $("#slot-letter-container");
  slotContainer.empty();

  var longestName = names.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
  });
  var totalLetters = longestName.replace(/\s/g, "").length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalLetters; i++) {
    var slotLetter = $('<span class="slot-letter"></span>');
    slotContainer.append(slotLetter);
  }

  $("body").css("background-image", "none");

  var interval = 100;
  var iterations = 50;

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
  var selectedName = names[randomIndex];
  var winnerLetters = selectedName.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");

  var currentIndex = 0;
  var rollingInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var slotLetters = $(".slot-letter");
    for (var i = 0; i < slotLetters.length; i++) {
      var randomLetter = generateRandomLetter();
      slotLetters.eq(i).text(randomLetter);
    }
  }, interval);

  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(rollingInterval);

    var spellingInterval = setInterval(function () {
      if (currentIndex >= winnerLetters.length) {
        clearInterval(spellingInterval);
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(".slot-letter").each(function (i) {
            if (i >= winnerLetters.length) {
              $(this).text("");
            }
          });
          $("body").css("background-image", "url(sunburst.svg)");

          const jsConfetti = new JSConfetti();
          jsConfetti.addConfetti({
            emojis: ["", "⚡️", "", "✨", "", ""],
          });

          confettiInterval = setInterval(function () {
            jsConfetti.addConfetti();
          }, 1000);

          isDrawing = false;
        }, 1000);
        return;
      }
      var currentLetter = winnerLetters[currentIndex];
      $(".slot-letter").eq(currentIndex).text(currentLetter);
      currentIndex++;
    }, interval);
  }, interval * iterations);
}

function stopConfetti() {
  if (confettiInterval) {
    clearInterval(confettiInterval);
    confettiInterval = null;
  }
}

function broadcastStartSlotMachine() {
  var channel = new BroadcastChannel("slotMachineChannel");
  channel.postMessage("startSlotMachine");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".draw-button").on("click", function () {
    if (!isDrawing) {
      stopConfetti();
      runSlotMachine();
      broadcastStartSlotMachine();
    }
  });
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var fullscreenButton = document.getElementById("fullscreen-button");

  fullscreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (
      !document.fullscreenElement &&
      !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
      !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&
      !document.msFullscreenElement
    ) {
      if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(
          Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT
        );
      }
    } else {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      }
    }
  });
});
$("#settings-button").click(function () {
  $(".settings").toggle();
});
$("#close-button").on("click", function () {
  $(".settings").hide();
});
$("#save-button").on("click", function () {
  $(".settings").hide();
});

const enableSoundCheckbox = document.getElementById("enable-sound");

const sound = document.getElementById("sound");

let shouldSave = false;

function toggleSound() {
  if (enableSoundCheckbox.checked) {
    sound.play();
  } else {
    sound.pause();
  }
}

function saveStateToLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("enableSound", enableSoundCheckbox.checked);
}

function loadStateFromLocalStorage() {
  const enableSound = localStorage.getItem("enableSound");
  if (enableSound === "true") {
    enableSoundCheckbox.checked = true;
    toggleSound();
  } else {
    enableSoundCheckbox.checked = false;
  }
}

enableSoundCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
  shouldSave = true;
});

const saveButton = document.getElementById("save-button");
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (shouldSave) {
    saveStateToLocalStorage();
    toggleSound();
  } else {
  }
  shouldSave = false;
});

loadStateFromLocalStorage();
```